# Latex: add figure number and caption automatically in a table

Tags: table-of-contents, word-to-latex

I'm writing my thesis and like in word i want to add the figure number and caption and the page number automatically in a table like (list of figures)
is it possible to do that in overleaf Latex or i need to do it manually

Comment: you question is rather unclear, automatic numbering is the default, `\caption{my table}` will allocate the next number to the table

Comment: i want to do list of figures so i want to add the number of the page the number of the figure and its caption in a table automatically like word

Comment: yes that's what `\caption` does but don't say `like word`  I only have a faint idea how word works, like most people here I use tex rather than Word.  You should show what you did and if you got an error say what error you got.

Comment: Did you already include the `\listoffigures` command in your document?

Comment: no i did not this is the first time i see this command i did my research but apparently not enough thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to TeX-SE.

Please, try the following MWE and if fits your needs. A figure follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{B}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{C}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]